# Is there any explicit narrations from companions or taba'in that prove that the Torah was textually corrupted?

Tags: torah

Is there any narration from Taba'in or companion of Holy Prophet Muhammad (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) that proves that the Torah was texually corrupted or changed? When I say Torah, what I mean is the entire old testament or the Hebrew Bible. Are there any narration from taba'in or companion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes from Ibn Abbas (RA):

Sahih Al Bukhari Volume 9, Book 93, Number 613:

> Ibn 'Abbaas said, "How can you ask the people of the Scriptures about
> their Books while you have Allah's Book (the Qur'an) which is the most
> recent of the Books revealed by Allah, and **you read it in its pure**
> **undistorted form?**"

Sahih Al Bukhari Volume 9, Book 93, Number 614:

> Narrated 'Ubaidullah bin 'Abdullah:'Abdullah bin 'Abbaas said, "O the
> group of Muslims! How can you ask the people of the Scriptures about
> anything while your Book, which Allah has revealed to your Prophet
> contains the most recent news from Allah and is pure and not
> distorted? **Allah has told you that the people of the Scriptures have**
> **changed some of Allah's Books and distorted it and wrote something**
> **with their own hands and said, 'This is from Allah, so as to have a**
> **minor gain for it**. Won't the knowledge that has come to you stop you
> from asking them? No, by Allah, we have never seen a man from them
> asking you about that (the Book Al-Qur'an ) which has been revealed to
> you.

Note that the verse Ibn Abbas is referring to is Quran 2:79.

Comment: Dear brother, I have some more questions to ask relating to this narration. If you permit me, then can I ask?

Comment: @Ren Sure brother, though it might be better to ask as a separate question.

Comment: Ibn Kathir also cites a narration by Wahb Bin Munabih, as Wahb bin Munabbih said, "The Tawrah and the Injil remain as Allah revealed them, and no letter in them was removed." You can find it [HERE](http://mquran.org/content/view/6698/2/)

Comment: Some people try to say that this narration is referrring to Qur'an 3:78 where it says, " And verily, among them is a party who distort the Book with their tongues (as they read), so that you may think it is from the Book, but it is not from the Book. What do you have to say about it?

Comment: Tafsir Ibn Kathir 2:75:"Wahb ibn Munabbih said: 'The Torah and the Gospel are just as Allah revealed them, not one word of them was changed, but they [the people] misguide others through tampering (tahrif), misinterpretation (ta’wil), and books (kutub) they wrote of their own then said it is from Allah when it is not from Allah. As for the books of Allah, they are preserved and do not change.'If Wahb meant the books that are in their hands, then there is no doubt at all that substitution (tabdil), tampering (tahrif), addition (ziyada), and omission (naqs) have entered into them."

Comment: The original meaning of the word Tahreef is "to lean from the pen in a certain direction" or 'to twist words to correspond to one's own desire." (Ar-Raghib Al-Isfahani, Al-Mufradat Fi Gharib Al-Qur'an, ed., by M. Ahmad Khalaf Allah, (Cairo, al-Anjilo al-Misriyya, 1965), vol. 1, pp.122f). Ash Shahrastani remarked that Tahreef means "changing the written word to an alternative to give it a corrupted meaning." (Ash-Shahrastani, op. cit., vol. 3, p. 11; Mujahid, op. cit., pp. 140)

Comment: Brother, did you trace the narration of Wahb ibn Munabih from original Arabic text of Ibn Kathir's commentary of that verse?

Comment: It's authentic but doesn't imply that the scriptures did not go under tahrif if you see verse 2;75 and it's tafsir as I provided above then you should understand. Also see the meaning of tahrif.

Comment: Thank you, brother. I will ask more questions, so I really hope you will remain on Islam Stack Exchange. Mashallah. You are knowledgeable. Jazakalalh.

Comment: Ok, will try to answer it if Ik